# JSON: How do i access "event" here so that i send it to a JOI middleware

Tags: javascript, sql, json, middleware, joi

So i have this JSON object:

```
{
    "event": [
        {
        "nombre_organizador": "A",
        "celular_organizador_secundario": "1234567891",
        "nombre_evento": "Torneo de comer"
        }
    ],
    "ticket":[
    {
        "nombre": "Boleto platino",
        "cantidad": null
    }
]
}
```

But i can't figure out how to only acces the event part using this validateSchema code, i am currenly writing it as:

```
export const validateCreateEvent = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { event } = req
  const validation = await validateSchema(createEventSchema, event)
  if (validation.err) {
    res.status(400).json({ msg: validation.err })
    console.log(event)
    return
  }
  next()
}
```

It returns the sql querie error as:

```
sql: "insert into `eventos` (`event`, `ticket`) values ('[object Object]', '[object Object]')"
```

And if i write the const as `{ event } = req.body` is says its an invalid object

Answer (score 0):

already solved, all i had to do was delete the square bracket within my JSON lmao